# Coldfusion Dropdown Query

Tags: jquery, sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

So need to do a query based on what is selected by the user. A dropdown menu with School, EID , Principal and Books are listed as options.When "School" is selected or clicked it would do a query on the sql-server database and throw in another drop down list for the user to select with all the values of the school. My English is not that great so this is what i mean

Dropdown -> If School is chosen - > kogod, SIS, Humane studies, Whartons school of Business etc. (from the database) will populate. -> if Wharton's is clicked it will show the table.So it is like a cascading dropdown based of off what is chosen..

So how do you do it? Code please give me the code. THanks

```
<cfform method="POST" action=""> <select name="one" required="yes" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<option>Select Type</option>
  <option value="school">School</option>
  <option value="EID">Electronic ID</option>
  <option value="prinical">Principal's Name</option>
  <option value="books">Books Used</option>
</select>
</cfform>

<cfquery name="schoollist" datasource="xxyyzz" dbtype="ODBC">
          select school_title, 
                      from DATABASENAME order by school_title
        </cfquery>

<cfif one.school is "selected?" from the first DROPDOWN then another drown down will pop up with the list of schools >
```

Help... Please

Comment: How is this different than your last question?

Comment: What Dan said, I don't see any readily apparent difference to the [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035576/static-dropdown-to-dynamic-dropdown-coldfusion). And specifically: _"please give me the code"_ - No. Stack Overflow is **not** a code writing service!

Comment: Changes rolled back to preserve context of accepted answer. If you have a *new* question, please open a new thread. You may want to read [Ask] and [How Stack Overflow Works](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote up a quick solution which you should be able to expand out to several levels deep easily enough.  Currently it just handles the first layer where you select a value from the first drop down and it shows you the next but you can apply the same concept multiple times.

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "one") and form.one neq "">
    <cfswitch expression="#form.one#">
        <cfcase value="school">
            <cfquery name="schoollist" datasource="xxyyzz" dbtype="ODBC">
              select school_title, 
              from DATABASENAME order by school_title
            </cfquery>

            <select name="schoollist" required="yes" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <cfoutput query="schoollist">
                    <option value="#schoollist.school_title#">#schoollist.school_title#</option>
                </cfoutput>
            </select>
        </cfcase>

        <cfcase value="EID">
            <cfquery name="eidlist" datasource="xxyyzz" dbtype="ODBC">
              select eid, 
              from DATABASENAME order by eid
            </cfquery>

            <select name="eidlist" required="yes" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <cfoutput query="eidlist">
                    <option value="#eidlist.eid#">#eidlist.eid#</option>
                </cfoutput>
            </select>
        </cfcase>

        <cfcase value="principle">
            <cfquery name="principle" datasource="xxyyzz" dbtype="ODBC">
              select principle, 
              from DATABASENAME order by principle
            </cfquery>

            <select name="principleList" required="yes" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <cfoutput query="principle">
                    <option value="#principle.principle#">#principle.principle#</option>
                </cfoutput>
            </select>
        </cfcase>

        <cfcase value="books">
            <cfquery name="books" datasource="xxyyzz" dbtype="ODBC">
              select books, 
              from DATABASENAME order by books
            </cfquery>

            <select name="books" required="yes" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <cfoutput query="books">
                    <option value="#books.books#">#books.books#</option>
                </cfoutput>
            </select>
        </cfcase>
    </cfswitch>
<cfelse>
    <cfform method="POST" action="#cgi.script_name#"> 
        <select name="one" required="yes" onchange="this.form.submit()">
          <option>Select Type</option>
          <option value="school">School</option>
          <option value="EID">Electronic ID</option>
          <option value="prinical">Principal's Name</option>
          <option value="books">Books Used</option>
        </select>
    </cfform>
</cfif>
```

You might also be able to simplify the code by doing something like this but I don't have the ability to test this at the moment so you might have to play around with it to get it to work:

```
    <cfif structKeyExists(form, "dropdown") and form.dropdown neq "">
    <!--- prevent sql injection, also serves to convert text in the database to valid table and column names for the next query--->
    <cfset sanitizedString = rereplacenocase(form.dropdown,'[^a-z_]','','all')>
    <!--- get data for drop down based on user selection --->
    <cfif structKeyExists(form, "rootType")>
        <cfset tableName = rereplacenocase(form.rootType,'[^a-z_]','','all')>
        <cfquery name="getInfo" datasource="mysql">
            SELECT * 
            FROM #tableName#
            WHERE #tableName# = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#form.dropdown#">
        </cfquery>

        <cfif getInfo.recordCount gt 0>
            <cfdump var="#getInfo#">
        <cfelse>
            No records were found.
        </cfif>
    <cfelse>
        <cfquery name="getDropDownData" datasource="mysql">
          select #sanitizedString#
          from #sanitizedString# order by <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#form.dropdown#">
        </cfquery>

        <cfform method="POST" action="#cgi.script_name#">
            <input type="hidden" name="rootType" value="<cfoutput>#form.dropdown#</cfoutput>">
            <select name="dropdown" required="yes" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                        <option value="">Select Value</option>
                <cfoutput query="getDropDownData">
                    <cfset val = getDropDownData["#sanitizedString#"]>
                    <option value='#val#'>#val#</option>
                </cfoutput>
            </select>
        </cfform>
    </cfif>
    <!--- redisplay the form --->

<cfelse>
    <cfform method="POST" action="#cgi.script_name#"> 
        <select name="dropdown" required="yes" onchange="this.form.submit()">
          <option>Select Type</option>
          <option value="school">School</option>
          <option value="EID">Electronic ID</option>
          <option value="principal">Principal's Name</option>
          <option value="books">Books Used</option>
        </select>
    </cfform>
</cfif>
```

Comment: I realize the above is just an example, but .. best not to use raw client values in sql, even in an example. Someone unfamiliar with web apps or CF might use the example "as is", not realizing they have just exposed their db to sql injection by using: `select #form.one# from DATABASENAME order by #form.one#`.

Comment: Updated second part of answer to protect against sql injection better.

Comment: Jason, I got the first layer down. How do you do the second layer. For example. If Wharton is selected it will do another query and give out all the details of the school. Can you please help me. I am learning CF but it is little touch for me.

Comment: I modified the second part of the answer to drill a little deeper.  It makes some assumptions like your table name is the same as the values from the first select box and the info you're looking for is also contained in that same table.  For example, if you select "Wharton" it will do `SELECT * FROM school WHERE school = 'Wharton'`.  

The more complicated you make this though the less this sort of solution fits it.  I would recommend doing this through an ajax call to a function that gets the results you're looking for as the answer linked at the top of this question suggests.